# Make footer stay at bottom without body { height: 100% }

Tags: html, css

If I set `html,body { height: 100% }` for my template, something weird happens. Its difficult to describe and also not possible to recreate the problem in a fiddle because it happens only at localhost. When I tried saving the page and then ran that page, the problem disappeared.

This is my problem:

I am trying to make the `footer` stay at bottom of my page if content doesn't fill the page, but if content overflows the page along y, footer should be at bottom of content, ie behave like a normal element.

I tried doing this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 60px;
}
```

This does work, but gives me a slight delay. When I refresh the page (when content not overflowing) the footer is at end of content not at bottom of page, as expected. But after about 0.5s, the footer goes at the bottom.

I have a CSS switcher button at bottom of my page, and when I use it, footer doesn't show this weird behaviour. So I think this is not CSS's fault. Also saving the page using `ctrl+s` and then running that saved page doesn't show this problem, so it probably is because of Django.

Here's my code: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/x6hmT/) and here's a RAR of that saved page: [**dropbox**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmjysngpoxfbl8b/COPE.rar)

Comment: Use `min-height` style in `.book-container`

Comment: It's HTML/CSS issue. If it's not working right, then maybe the styles are overlapping. Use the `Inspect Element` feature of your browser to check. It can only be Django issue if the style tags or css files are not loading right.

Comment: @mshsayem I can't use `min-height` as it won't work on all resolutions.

Comment: @Bibhas if it is HTML/CSS problem, then why isn't it happening in saved page?

Comment: Do you want [sticky footer](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sticky+footer)?

Comment: @Sourabh saved page can break things in so many ways for a dynamic website. I don't know why you're doing that. When you save the page, maybe some 3rd party style fails to load, something that was colliding with your style. Or maybe you're loading some styles dynamically which are unavailable in saved page. So many other things can go wrong. Inspect and check.

Comment: And if it's a Django problem, there is absolutely no way for us to understand that from the given code.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a min-height to your container div && apply a padding-bottom to your body div that matches the height of the footer.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xdFR/)**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body">
        <!-- content here -->

    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>

html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

Comment: the problem occurs if `body` has `height: 100%` so this doesn't solve the problem. Also, making `container { height: 100% }`, which is `book-container` in my case, makes it as long as `body`